# Send Email using firebase logged in user as a sender

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

Using firebase authentication to login users. Once user is logged in, user need to send an email notification to his clients email. 
I found the only way is to use nodemailer that does require sender email and password. 
How can we get logged-in user password using AngularFireAuth?
Is there another way where I can use firebase logged-in user token to send an email?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the password of a user from Firebase Authentication. That would be a *serious* security risk.

But nodemailer is likely more interested in getting [credentials for sending mail](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#authentication) through the SMTP mail server you're using. These are credentials from **you** that it uses to send the email, and they are not necessarily the same as the credentials of the user you're sending email to.

Comment: I'm interested in logged-in user credentials because the logged in user is the sender.

Comment: There is no way to get their password from Firebase Authentication. There's also no guarantee that the password they used to sign in to Firebase would be the same password as they use to access their mail server.